# Auto submit data to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am teaching myself code, and after going over PHP & MySQL tutorials, I'm still a little unsure.

I want to create a page in which the user ticks relevant checkboxes, saves the data, and can log back in another time and the ticks are saved.

I've learned how to use data that is in MySQL, but how is data auto-submitted by the user? That's got me stumped...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `form`:

http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/forms.php

```
<form method="post" action="/your/php/script.php">
    Name: <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="40" name="name"> <br />
    Password: <input type="password" size="10" maxlength="10" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The page listed in `action` then reads the form and saves the data to the database. Michael should have added a submit button.

Comment: Ok thanks. So what needs to be on the page I'm sending this data to? (e.g. your/php.script.php)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a question than can be answered simply, but here's the Simple answer.

First, put your checkboxes in a form:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="SomeValue">SomeValue</input>
</form>
```

Then, in page2.php, put the data (which is in the $*POST array) into the MySql database using the mysql** functions (mysql_connect, mysql_select_db, mysql_query, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```
<?php
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    $query = "SELECT * FROM example";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
    ?>
    <form action="" method=post>
    <b>Company Name</b> <input name="CompanyName" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['company'] ?>" /><br>
    <b>First Name</b> <input name="firstname" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['firstname'] ?>"/><br>
    <b>Last Name</b> <input name="lastname" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['lastname'] ?>" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```